# Is it possible to create an overridable inflatable airlock seal?

Tags: spacecraft, eva, technology, airlock

If the information I obtained is correct, inflatable airlocks are sealed by the air pressure and cannot be unlocked unless the pressure is lowered(correct me if I'm wrong).

Additionally, airlocks usually open "inwards". To be able to override this, they should open outwards, however, this will lessen its sealing ability.

Some inflatable airlocks are the MASH, AIA and LEIA. Also, I found a video on YouTube on operating the MASH. My apologies, I can't seem to find the link on where I read about the seals opening inwards.

Do inflatable airlocks that can be opened without lowering the pressure exist?

If not, is there any possible way to create this?

Comment: Can you give an example or links to the "inflatable airlocks" you are talking about?

Comment: There's no such thing as an inflatable airlock, except in science fiction.

Comment: @GdD not exactly... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voskhod_2

Comment: @GdD: Voskhod 2 -- the first spacewalk -- had an inflatable airlock, but it also had problems re-sealing.  I'm not aware of any since then.

Comment: I thought it was an inflatable tube, not an actual airlock. Now I'm confused.

Comment: It was an airlock.  They had to keep air in the cabin to properly cool the vacuum tubes.  (Seriously!)

Comment: @Zan you should [edit] your question and include that information. The less effort someone has to go to in order to figure out what you are asking, the better chance you have of getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fabulous overview of inflatable airlocks past, present, and future in this presentation

[DEVELOPMENT OF AN INFLATABLE AIRLOCK FOR DEEP SPACE EXPLORATION](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20180007255.pdf)

From Voskhod's Volga

[image]

to all the more recent designs

[image]

To actually address your question

> Do inflatable airlocks that can be opened without lowering the
>   pressure exist?

If you mean *opening the outer airlock hatch without lowering the pressure in the lock chamber to near-vacuum*....not really. Imagine what would happen if you opened an outward-opening hatch in that situation. Explosive decompression!

And why would you want to? The US airlock on the International Space Station scavenges much of the air back into the station so it isn't wasted.